# I need quick tips on modifying this 2d platformer (placeholder) code for my needs with unity. These don't feel right to me

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller

I am currently in school learning c# and I am a long time gamer. I just finished a game development class using Unity and now I'm trying to make a game to learn with trial and error.

Currently I have a basic understanding of c#, just not very practical. Until I get farther into my course, I need to borrow code as a placeholder.

This code was provided to me as a basic player controller script. I intend on using it until I can create my own controller code from scratch, this will just be for prototyping and debugging.

The code below (besides spelling radius wrong) has 2 major problems with it that I have tried fixing to my liking but I keep breaking the code.

PROBLEM 1 (Regarding the control input)

I don't want to control the game with the wasd keys. I want to use the arrow keys to move left and right. I want 'z' to be my jump key instead of 'w'.

PROBLEM 2 (Regarding the post-jump velocity)

When the character jumps, it keeps floating in the direction it was walking before the jump. I want it to be stationary in the air unless the directional buttons are pressed in the air.

I want this game to control in a similar way to IWBTB or IWBTG while I create the levels and finish my class.

Here is the code:

(I am also open to any new code that has the same functionality without the animations.)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class playercontroller : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speedForce= 50f;
    public Vector2 jumpVector;
    public bool isGrounded;
    float speed;

    public Transform grounder;
    public float radiuss;
    public LayerMask ground;

    Animator anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {

            speed = isGrounded ? speedForce : speedForce*0.7f;
                        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (-speed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
                        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1, 1, 1);
                        anim.SetInteger ("AnimationState", 1);

                } else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
            speed = isGrounded ? speedForce : speedForce*0.7f;
                        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (speed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
                        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1);
                        anim.SetInteger ("AnimationState", 1);
                } else if(isGrounded)
                {
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (0, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
            anim.SetInteger("AnimationState", 0); 

                } 

        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (grounder.transform.position, radiuss, ground); 

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W) && isGrounded == true) {
                        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce (jumpVector, ForceMode2D.Force);

                }    
    }

    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.white;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (grounder.transform.position, radiuss);    
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "deadly") {
            Debug.Log("Dead!");
            Application.LoadLevel(0);    
                }
        }

    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "deadly") {
            Debug.Log("Dead!");
            Application.LoadLevel(0);               
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) 
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "deadly") {
            Debug.Log("Dead!");
            Application.LoadLevel(0);               
        }
    }    
}
```

I don't want to use borrowed code. This is strictly to be used as a placeholder for level design. I am new to the c# language but I plan on being fluent in it at some point in my life.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to C#. It's awesome. Can't answer your second question (No Unity etc...) but you can obviously see where the movement with `KeyCode` is done, yes? Documentation is your friend: Have a look at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html (S.O. Isn't parsing the link properly... sorry), it tells you all the `KeyCode`s that Unity uses. You're looking for `KeyCode.LeftArrow`, `KeyCode.RightArrow` and `KeyCode.Z`

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

Change your below code

```
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A))
```

to this

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
```

and this one

```
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D))
```

to this

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
```

I think now you can handle the 'z' part yourself.

**Problem 2**

Add the following code

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (0, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
anim.SetInteger("AnimationState", 0);
```

above this one

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce (jumpVector, ForceMode2D.Force);
```

so your final code snippet should look like this.

```
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Z) && isGrounded == true) {
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (0, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
anim.SetInteger("AnimationState", 0);
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce (jumpVector, ForceMode2D.Force);
   }
```